# Load different routes on beta server than on main server?

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm using react and react-router-dom for my website.  I have two versions of the site, one that it for beta users and the other that is for my customers.  When the site is loaded on the beta server with `process.env.IS_BETA === "true"` I only want users to be able to access the login and forgot my password pages.  I don't want them to access the registration page or the front page.  I tried the following but it didn't work because I think the `process.env` is already read when it's built.

```
export const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="d-flex flex-column height-100vh">
            <Navbar />
                {process.env.IS_BETA === "true" && (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                        <Route path="/TermsOfUse" component={TermsOfUse} />

                        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
                        <Route path="/Reset" component={Reset} />

                        <Redirect to="/Login" />
                    </Switch>
                )}
                {process.env.IS_BETA !== "true" && (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                        <Route path="/TermsOfUse" component={TermsOfUse} />

                        <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
                        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
                        <Route path="/Reset" component={Reset} />

                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                )}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

How do I redirect or not load some pages on the beta server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.env` is not available direclty in your Javascript code, but it will be available to Webpack at compile time. Webpack supports defining globals within your Javascript environment with the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), so by adding a new plugin definition as follows:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __IS_BETA__: process.env.IS_BETA === "true",
    }),
],
```

in your Webpack config, `__IS_BETA__` will be replaced throughout your Javascript code based on whether IS_BETA environment variable was set to true when compiling your app.

You can then reference it in your React code as such:

```
export const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="d-flex flex-column height-100vh">
            <Navbar />
                {__IS_BETA__ && (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                        <Route path="/TermsOfUse" component={TermsOfUse} />

                        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
                        <Route path="/Reset" component={Reset} />

                        <Redirect to="/Login" />
                    </Switch>
                )}
                {!__IS_BETA__ && (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                        <Route path="/TermsOfUse" component={TermsOfUse} />

                        <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
                        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
                        <Route path="/Reset" component={Reset} />

                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                )}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Where do I put the first chunk of code?

Comment: @Dev01 it really depends on the structure of your app, but within the main server-side part of the app that renders the HTML and sends to client. Please note that if you're not using server-side rendering a completely different approach is necessary. There's not enough info in your original question to tell the full setup.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'm not using server-side rendering.  I've been thinking about looking into using server-side rendering but haven't gotten around to it.  Right now I just want to release the site as is for the beta users and then I can fix things like the server side rendering.  How would I do this if I don't use server-side rendering?

Comment: Ok, if you're using Webpack you can process environment variables into globals at compile time. I will update my answer when I'm back in front of computer.

Comment: Thanks, I am using webpack.

Comment: @Dev01 I've updated the answer now for webpack compile time